# Получить содержимое canvas в виде пригодном для записи в файл

Tags: node.js, webkit, canvas, javascript

Веб-приложение работает на node-webkit, как следствие доступ к фс есть. Нужно получить содержимое canvas в пригодном для записи в файл виде.

Comment: btw - посмотрите в сторону [appjs](github.com/appjs/appjs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var binary = atob(canvas.toDataURL().replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, ""));
fs.writeFile('path/to/the/file.png', binary, 'binary', function() {
   // ...
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Использовал вот эту библиотеку: [canvas2image](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/)

Пример использования найдёте там же, нечего добавить. В коде можете посмотреть как из канваса достаются бинарные данные.